# Python subprocess.run() batch file with updating variables

Tags: python, batch-file, subprocess

I want to ask how can I run an external batch file while updating the variable before I run the process. The detail for my question is following:

I have a batch file right now, while it performs a simulation process. I want to write a module that I can update the variable first without manually updating the batch files, then run the simulation, and finally import the result, like:

```
# this will be the variable that I want to update
yyyy = 2022
mm = 11
dd = 28
Path1 = 'the path for first variable'
Path2 = 'the path for second variable'


# the batch file is like:
Batch_simulation.bat
Path 2/remote/noclear/Path 1/%yyyy%%mm%%dd%


# therefore, I want to update the variable in batch file first, then run the simulation, my code is looking like this right now:
import subprocess

yyyy = 2022
mm = 11
dd = 28
Path1 = 'the path for first variable'
Path2 = 'the path for second variable'

paramStr = str(yyyy)+','+str(mm)+','+str(dd)+','+Path1+','+Path2
bat_file = ['pathway for Batch_simulation.bat', paramStr]
process = subprocess.run([bat_file])
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
```

Can someone give some advice, or any possible solution please? Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone give ... any possible solution ...?

- in a loop

  - [open and read the batch file](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) (--> results in a string)
  - use [pattern matching](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/stdlib.html#string-pattern-matching) to find then replace the relevant parts of that string with your data
  - write the modified string to the batch file
  - run the batch file with subprocess and get its results.

Comment: Would you mind give more details about this approach, please?

Comment: Take each bullet and implement it in code; using functions may help segregate the individual parts; opening/reading/writing files is pretty self explanatory;  finding and replacing text in a string may need some study/practice/searching if you are not familiar with this. Use the python documentation Tutorial links I included for a start, The Python docs have detailed  info in the [Library Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html) section. Many variations  of all of those bullets have been asked and answered here on SO, searching should prove fruitful.

Answer (score 0):

I know python not at all.

It would appear to me that the string presented to the batch would be

```
yyyy,mm,dd,Path1,Path2
```

So within the batch, `%1` would deliver `yyyy`, `%2` would deliver `mm` and so on.

Note : if `Path?` contains a separator like <kbd>Space</kbd> then the value `path?` must be quoted `"path?"`. Probably best to quote these elements in any case. (spaces, commas and some other characters are separators for batch)

Please also note that batch requires a backslash as directory-separator, not forward-slash.